# Numpy: select along axis of 3d array using 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I've been struggling with this for a few hours and can't quite get my head around it. The setup is something like this:

```
    A.shape # (T,N,K)
    B.shape #   (L,K) L < N
```

Each of the K columns of the 2D B array index one of the N columns along that same K row. I can grab along any specific k slice easily via

```
    A[:,B[:,k],k].shape # (T,L)
```

However, looping over K isn't ideal because A is a very large matrix

I'm sure someone has a really simple answer, but I am stumped.

Edit: I should also add that I need to preserve the 3D structure of the A matrix. I figured out how to grab the individual values, but only in a (TxLxK,) array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.take_along_axis`

```
np.take_along_axis(A,B[None,...],axis=1)
```

For example,

```
A = np.linspace(1,24,24).reshape(3,4,2)
B = np.repeat([[0,1]],3,axis=0)

np.take_along_axis(A,B[None,...],axis=1)
```

the result is

```
array([[[ 1.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  4.]],

       [[ 9., 12.],
        [ 9., 12.],
        [ 9., 12.]],

       [[17., 20.],
        [17., 20.],
        [17., 20.]]])
```